# CMSampleBuffer convert BGRA to YUV 420f

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I'm working on a project where I capture the video input of user with `AVCaptureSession`. The thing is I need the output in BGRA format to render it with OpenCV, but then I need to change it back to the default 420f format to display it to the user. So, I set `PixelFormatType` in `videoSettings` to `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA`,

```
[videoOutput setVideoSettings:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey]];
```

and I want to convert the sample buffer to 420f in captureOutput:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
    [self doSomeOpenCV:sampleBuffer]; // the OpenCV part

    //convert sampleBuffer to kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange

}
```

Is there a way to do so? Or maybe, there is a function that returns a samplebuffer in specified format given the input?

Comment: How are you displaying the frames to the user? Why does that require yuv?

Comment: Yes with https://developer.apple.com/documentation/videotoolbox/vtpixeltransfersession-7cg

Comment: @RhythmicFistman i'm using google's webRTC framework, which uses yuv pixelFormatType

Comment: @Valérian it doesn't seem to work on iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use an `AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer` to display your BGRA sample buffers and ditch webRTC (at least for display purposes)?

If you don’t want do that, you can of course convert your BGRA buffers to YUV, and you can even do it quite efficiently on the GPU, but the best conversion is no conversion and besides who wants to type that much on an iPad screen keyboard?

Comment: I need webRTC to make an online video calls like in viper, and I can't modify their code, so I can't use AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer as far as I discovered. I just have to pass theCMSampleBuffer object to webRTC so it handles the rest. That's why I search for a way to convert BGRA to YUV

Comment: Are you sure webRTC _doesn't_ support `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA`? Its class `RTCCVPixelBuffer` supports BGRA and has a `toI420` (yuv) method. You could use it, directly or indirectly.

Comment: hmm, thanks for mentioning it. I checked and couldn't find the class. I guess the example project that I am using: https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-ios doesn't include the whole framework. I tried to build webRTC manually, but it really seems to have problems with Xcode building. But I feel like there should be an easier solution for this.

Comment: which classes/methods are you using in `apprtc-ios` to display yuv sample buffers?

Comment: in `ARDAppClient` class there is a method called `createLocalVideoTrack` which handles the video capturing, where it uses `RTCVideoSource` by default, but I changed it to `RTCAVFoundationVideoSource`, which has `AVCaptureSession` property, and then I just modify the session.